# How to get week number based on a changing start date?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table within my Power BI report that looks like this:

```
Date     | Offer | Offer_start | Offer_end |Offer_day
---------|-------|-------------|-----------|---------
15/03/24 |A      |15/03/24     |17/03/24   |1
16/03/24 |A      |15/03/24     |17/03/24   |2 
17/03/24 |A      |15/03/24     |17/03/24   |3
18/03/24 |B      |18/03/24     |20/03/24   |1
31/12/24 |C      |31/12/24     |10/01/25   |1
01/01/25 |C      |31/12/24     |10/01/25   |2
```

A new row is added daily, with the Date column defined as the current day.

The Offer_day column is a calculated column defined like this:

```
Offer_day = datediff(mytable[Offer_start], mytable[Date], day)+1
```

There should never be two offers active at the same time.

I want to add a column flagging what week an offer is in on each date. However, the weeks should be defined as Sunday to Saturday. So the desired result would look like this:

| Date | Offer | Offer_start | Offer_end | Offer_day | Offer_week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15/03/24 | A | 15/03/24 | 17/03/24 | 1 | 1 |
| 16/03/24 | A | 15/03/24 | 17/03/24 | 2 | 1 |
| 17/03/24 | A | 15/03/24 | 17/03/24 | 3 | 2 |
| 18/03/24 | B | 18/03/24 | 20/03/24 | 1 | 1 |
| 31/12/24 | C | 31/12/24 | 10/01/25 | 1 | 1 |
| 01/12/25 | C | 31/12/24 | 10/01/25 | 2 | 1 |

On 17/03/24 the offer week becomes week 2 because 17/03/24 is a Sunday, even though offer A is only on its third day. The following day, the offer week returns to week 1 because it is the first week of a new offer.

Does anyone know how to do this please?

EDIT: Offers can start in one year and finish in another, so the solution would have to accommodate this as well. I've added a couple of rows to my example to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the week number for the offer start date and the week number for the current row date to find the difference in weeks between the current date and the offer start date.
If there is no difference or if the current date is in the same week as the offer start, it returns 1. Otherwise, it increments the week number based on the difference that you calculated.

```
Offer_week = 
VAR OfferStartWeek = WEEKNUM(mytable[Offer_start], 1) 
VAR CurrentDateWeek = WEEKNUM(mytable[Date], 1)
VAR WeekDifference = CurrentDateWeek - OfferStartWeek
RETURN IF(WeekDifference >= 0, WeekDifference + 1, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This works for the most part, but what about if an offer spans the end of one year and the start of the next (say, Offer_start is 15/12/24 and Offer_end is 15/01/25)? In this case wouldn't your Offer_week column start returning 1 again from 01/01/25?

Comment: The solution I added answers what you provided in your question. What you are telling now is new to the original rule. So you may need to specify more clarifications

Comment: I've added some more detail to the original question to make it clear that offers can start in one calendar year and finish in another.

Comment: Can you add a line to your data for what you explained

Comment: I've added some extra data to show what I would want to happen if an offer starts in one year and finishes in another.

Comment: @SRJCoding after adding the last rows your Offer_day column will give 336 and not 2 ? how do u explain this ?